# Azure DevOps API - git log equivalent

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to replicate this git command: `git log "$labelCommit..HEAD" --decorate` using the Azure [Devops api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#reachable-from-a-commit)

I thought this would do the trick:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.compareVersion.version=$labelCommit&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType=commit&api-version=6.0-preview.1`

But I just seem to keep getting everything back. Looking at my repo I should get 7 commits back, but I can get thousands.

The documentation is non-existent on what `searchCriteria.compareVersion` is or how to use it, what the various options actually mean.

Has anyone achieved anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this gives me what I want:

```
var gitQueryCommitsCriteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria()
        {
            CompareVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor()
            {
                Version = branchName,
                VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch
            },
            Top = 10000,
            IncludeLinks = true,
            IncludeWorkItems = true,
            ItemVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor()
            {
                Version = tagName,
                VersionType = GitVersionType.Tag,
                VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
            }

        };

        var commits = await GitHttpClient.GetCommitsAsync("projectName", repo, gitQueryCommitsCriteria);
```